# copying values from parent scope to directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and was wondering how I would go about copying the values in my parent scope to my directive scope with no bindings (2 separate instances).  Currently my implementation goes as is, with my newHostTemplate calling `{{newHost.ipAddress}}` however I want newHost to be from the directives scope and not the parent.

```
host.directive('newHost', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.newBox = function() {
                scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
                    return 'hosts/newHostTemplate.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

host.controller('hostsController', function($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
        console.log("failed to change routes");
    });

    $scope.newHost = {};
    $scope.addNewHost = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://192.168.0.99:5000/newHost',
            data    : JSON.stringify($scope.newHost),  // pass in data as strings
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.newBox()
            $scope.newHost = {}
            //on success we want to close the modal and reset the data
            $scope.dismiss()
        });
    };
});
```

Currently when I run this I get an error saying newBox is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You want to isolate the scope. Instead of **scope: true**, do **scope: {}**.

Any explicit input from the parent to the directive would be through defined scope variables:

```
scope: {
    twoWayBoundInputOne: '=',
    staticStringInputTwo: '@',
    functionThree: '&'
}
```

Also, recommended architecture is to put reusable code, such as AJAX requests into a service.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Inject the service into the directive and controller the same way you inject $scope or $http.

Your service may look like:

```
/* global bz_app */
host.factory('hostsService', ['$http',
function ($http) {
    return function () {
        this.add = function () {
            return $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'http://192.168.0.99:5000/newHost',
                data    : JSON.stringify($scope.newHost),  // pass in data as strings
            });
        };

        this.templateUrl = function() {
                return 'hosts/newHostTemplate.html';
        };
    };
}]);

// then in your controller or directive you can do this, to get an instance that doesn't get impacted by other instances.
scope.host = new HostsService();
```

Comment: Hi Artem,  how would the above scope apply to my scenario

Comment: Your scope input would be scope: { host: '=' } and you would pass in the scope.newHost from the controller to the directive via <new-host host="newHost"></new-host>

Comment: Why do you have the template with ng-include of a static template URL instead of using templateUrl: ''hosts/newHostTemplate.html''? This will prevent additional scoping created by ng-include. The template will live directly in the scope of the directive.

Comment: I want to be able to append only on success callback form the http request

Comment: Artem, I have carried out your suggestion, however I get a  $scope.newBox is not a function.  I am guessing this is not a function anymore because I have declared my scope as isolated?

Comment: Possible - I would need to see the latest code to tell. As I mentioned - you don't need the function to get the template path. You should use templateUrl: "your path" instead of template: "..."